# Make shell script default to run file extension

Tags: scripts, menu, appmenu, default, default-programs

I'm trying to make the default application for .asm file extension to be a shell script that I made. Basically I have a .sh script that runs MIPS Mars and I want to make it the default application to open assembly .asm files. My problem is that while I can add my .sh script to the app menu using main menu app from the store, I can't make my script appear in the list of open with programs for .asm files.

Answer (score 4):

You can try creating a `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` (or `~/.local/share/applications`, if only for one user) like explained [here](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en) (works for other desktops too).

To link this program to `.asm` files you first have to create a mimetype for `.asm` files.

In order to do so you have to add/modify the line

```
text/x-asm                asm
```

in `/etc/mime.types`

In the `.desktop` file you should add the line

```
MimeType=text/x-asm;
```

so it's added to the "Open with" menu.

To finally make your script the default application for `.asm` files add

```
text/x-asm=yourscript.desktop
```

to `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`

Edit: To make it work immediately you should probably run `update-desktop-database` after your changes.

Comment: It should help, upvote for you!