# Trouble Running C++ Executable from Desktop

Tags: c++, executable

I created a basic Hello World program in c++:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>




int main(){


std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

return 0;
}
```

And compiled it with g++ gui.cpp -o GUI. I can run it by typing ./GUI in the command line but when I click it on my Desktop I get no results. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Nautilus to allow executing the file as program in right click -> properties

[image]

Also, you're outputing the string to stdout, which is console. You can only see that in terminal

Comment: Was my first thought, but did not help.

Comment: I noticed that you also are outputing that to stdout, which is console. I don't think you will be able to see that in gui

Comment: Yes, but it's not opening up a command line either.

Comment: Yeah, it's not gonna do it, unless you actually tell it to open a terminal window. I'm not sure how that could be done in c++. I know in c you could use exec() function. Such simple program isn't really meant to be run in gui, really

Comment: What you can do is open terminal window (ctrl+alt+t), drag and drop the executable, and hit enter

Comment: is there a way to make gnome automatically open a program with terminal?

Comment: [There is](http://askubuntu.com/a/519924/295286), but requires installing a plug in for the file manager

Comment: Now, as for your question in general, it's actually off-topic on this site. Askubuntu is mostly about ubuntu OS related questions, yours - is about programming in general, which belongs at stackexchange.com. I know you're a new user, so just giving heads up. In future, just post OS related questions here. Otherwise it will be closed/deleted pretty fast

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21620/discussion-between-user2707299-and-serg).

Comment: @user2707299 You can create a `.desktop` file for your application which will open the terminal for you...  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby That's RIGHT !

Comment: How do you do this, Fabby ? You're so smart !

Comment: You just didn't think of this, but now you will!  ;-)

Comment: -_- but then  again, you have to create .desktop file for every executable ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/592627/295286